# globalize check number or date

Tags: jquery, jquery-globalize

I have defined a function where I am receiving a value in the function that I know it should be a number and I am using the following code

```
less = Globalize.numberParser()(value);
```

Now I want to use the same function for dates. 
Is there a function in Globalize project to determine if the value is a number or a date?

Comment: Like [this](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/blob/master/doc/api/date/date-formatter.md)?

Comment: @Tico I know about the dateFormatter, I am asking for a boolean function or an if statement to determine if the value is a number or a date